# is there anything to customize avatar like bitmoji with choose face shape Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[I want to customize avatar like bitmoji with choose face shape and choose all options like hair, beard,.....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNEE7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think I get your question right.

Have you checked if any plugins do it? Maybe you can try out [Flutter-Moji](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttermoji), had a bug last time I used it, but it's probably fixed by now.

Comment: i want to change face shape like i change skin color and all options.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. There is a very nice package developed for this.
https://pub.dev/packages/fluttermoji

good coding

Comment: Really,this package is very nice but i want to change face shape like i change skin color and all options.